# How to compile Java code without an IDE?

Tags: java, ide, editor, development-environment

I am a beginning programmer that has been using an IDE to learn to code. However I want to try  using a text editor to see which one I would like more. My question is, once you download a text editor, what tools do you need to compile and run a program and how do you set them up?

Comment: What operating system do you have ? (Windows ?)

Answer (score 3):

You just need [the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). Installing it (it has an installer) should set it up sufficiently.

When you want to compile something, use the `javac` tool:

```
> javac MyClass.java
```

When you want to run something, most likely you'll want the `java` tool (although of course if you're doing servlets or such, you'd use something else):

```
> java MyClass
```

Or of course, go ahead and use a separate text editor if you like but continue to use the IDE to compile, not least because presumably any IDE you were using had an integrated debugger, and a debugger is an essential tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a text editor for java programming don't forget to add java to your Environment Variables Path. You can check if java is already added to your path by running `java -version` in your command line. If you get nothing you have to add  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0;` to your path (your version of the jdk may be different, change it to the name you have). Don’t forget that semi-colon **;** at the end.

Now you are set and ready to compile and run java programs just as explained by @T.J. Crowder in the answer above.